# python - How to use regex to delimit input

Tags: python, regex, input

Say I'm reading directly from an HTML document in my code. Each line looks something like the following:

```
<TD>field1</TD><TD><A HREF="http://sample.url.com">field2</TD><TD><EM>field3</EM></TD>
```

I want to write code that can easily pick out the fields `field1`, `field2`, and `field3`. I know that every single line of this table is going to be the exact same format, besides each of these fields.

I'm not that familiar with regex, but in my research I've only ever seen it used for *searching* for known tokens amongst unknown tokens, rather than *isolating* unknown tokens among known tokens. Due to my inexperience with regex my example will essentially follow the pattern of a C string formatter (using `%s` for an input token).

So basically, I want to be able to implement the following method with regex:

```
(field1, url, field2, field3) = regex_extract('<TD>%s</TD><TD><A HREF="%s">%s</TD><TD><EM>%s</EM></TD>')
```

Is this a thing that's possible with regex?

Comment: DON'T use regex for HTML, use a HTML parser like [beautifulsoup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/)

Comment: It is possible indeed, but really, using a html parser will make your life much easier (and your code much more maintainable).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use regex, here's yours:

```
import re

a = "<TD>field1</TD><TD><A HREF=\"http://sample.url.com\">field2</TD><TD><EM>field3</EM></TD>"
REGEX = r'<TD>(\w+)</TD><TD><A HREF="([A-Za-z/:.]+)">(\w+)</TD><TD><EM>(\w+)</EM></TD>'
print(re.findall(REGEX, a))
>>>> [('field1', 'http://sample.url.com', 'field2', 'field3')]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like:

```
import re
pattern = re.compile('<TD>(?P<field1>.*?)</TD><TD><A HREF="(?P<url>.*?)">(?P<field2>.*?)</TD><TD><EM>(?P<field3>.*?)</EM></TD>')

html = '<TD>field1</TD><TD><A HREF="http://sample.url.com">field2</TD><TD><EM>field3</EM></TD>'
match = pattern.search(html)
if match:
    field1, url, field2, field3 = match.groups()
    # or you can do field1 = match.group('field1') and so on....
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you the following simple solution, returning fields and optionnaly the url in a list:

```
import re

s = "<TD>field1</TD><TD><A HREF=\"http://sample.url.com\">field2</TD><TD><EM>field3</EM></TD>"

# If you want to extract the URL
myPattern = re.compile(r'<TD>(\w+)</TD><TD><A HREF=(.+)>(\w+)</TD><TD><EM>(\w+)</EM></TD>')
listOfMatches = list(myPattern.findall(s)[0])
print(listOfMatches) # ['field1', '"http://sample.url.com"', 'field2', 'field3']

# If you don't want to extract the URL
myPattern = re.compile(r'<TD>(\w+)</TD><TD><A HREF=.+>(\w+)</TD><TD><EM>(\w+)</EM></TD>')
listOfMatches = list(myPattern.findall(s)[0])
print(listOfMatches) # ['field1', 'field2', 'field3']
```